# I am trying to download XDM(xtreme download manager) on kali linux but i get a java error

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I've downloaded its .deb installation file from source forge. I am trying to install it using `sudo dpkg -i` but I get the following error. Also I've tried `apt-get update`/`upgrade`. Didn't work.

```
Unpacking xdman (5.0-build-74) over (5.0-build-74) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xdman:
 xdman depends on openjdk-6-jre | openjdk-7-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre is not installed.
  Package openjdk-7-jre is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xdman (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-8) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xdman
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem while trying to install from deb with gdebi in Linux Mint: it asked for java 6, 7 or higher, while 8 was already installed.

The solution is to install with the installation script - not from deb - as described [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/xdman/blog/2018/03/how-to-install-xdm-on-any-linux-distribution/).

Download and unpack from [here](http://xdman.sourceforge.net/#downloads). Go to the folder created thus, open a terminal there and do:

```
sudo su
./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This error says that xdman package has dependency on openjdk-6-jre / openjdk-7-jre, and it is not install.

Run below mentioned command to install openjdk-7-jre, after that try to install xdman pkg.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```